# Using cascades optionally in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

my problem is quite simple, but very important in general - I think. I have done research for a few hours but didn't find anything useful.

Introduction:
I have entity that is named Employee - which is central class of my system(lets say its HR Management). By writing central I have on my mind that it has many relations to other entites. There are OneToOne, OneToMany and ManyToOne properties in it. 
Problem:
In some cases I have to refresh this entity(it has also basic properties like 'String name;' and so on) - after it was changed in one EntityManager context(hibernate Session) and has to be refreshed in other. Of course I can use for it:

```
entityManager.refreash(employee);
```

but... it also will refresh like "one hundred" related entites(mentioned: 1-1, *-1, 1-* relations), because those relations have annotation parameter Cascade.All or Cascade.REFREASH for them.  What is not needed in that situation - I only use Employee entity itself in this context. And what is NOT WANTED because it will strike performance and even locally takes like 0.5 s...
Question:
Is there any way to refresh entity optionally "turning off" cascades on its properties. Or maybe: is there any way to refresh only specific properties of entity using Hibernate/JPA??

I really don't want those 20 ore more long SQL queries triggered by Hibernate, when I refresh my entity in those situations, but in other situations it is wanted.

In other words, I would say that I need option like "respectCascadesOnRefresh=true/false" that can be set before refreash.

Any other ideas?

Any help appreciated,

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, if you have only two or three fields to refresh, use criteria api.
- Secondly, Cascade is not a good thing in absolute context - you'd better resolve some of the dependecies manually.
- Thirdly, use `FetchType.LAZY` for collections!

P.S. And NO, you can't use cascade manually, as this annotations are used once while generating your db scheme.

Comment: 1. Hmmm... not exactly the right option in this case, because this is not some "manual refresh", insteed it is executed by my framework automatic mechanism, so the option like "respectCascadesOnRefresh=true/false" would be useful. Criteria - I don't see them useful in this situation.  2. You are probably right:) 3. They are NOT respected with refresh. P.S. I don't use hibernate to generate my db schema. Isn't it for production "mode" only?

Comment: 3. And this don't resolve the 1-1 and *-1 relations. And: I use them:) Thanks for answer!!! :)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write: "P.S. I don't use hibernate to generate my db schema. Isn't it for development "mode" only?" And it is.

Comment: Since I didn't get better answers I'm accepting Yours. But was hoping for something better for my situation...:/ Thanks again! :)