# JPA/Hibernate Cascade ALL causes redundant left outer join

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, cascade

i have a simple Entity GeneralUser below (not needed fields are ommited)

```
public class GeneralUser
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String fname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fromGeneralUser", targetEntity = Friendship.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Friendship> friendships;
}
```

Let me give you a very simple example of what i do:

```
GeneralUser user = generalUserService.find(id);
user.setFname("foo")
user = generalUserService.merge(user);
```

The problem i face is that hibernate before merge user performs a select from database which is more complicated than it should be. More specific the select makes a left outer join with the "friendships" relationship (table) defined above (relationship OneToMany).

Any tip to avoid this?

if i change this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fromGeneralUser", targetEntity = Friendship.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DELETE)
```

then it works ok, so it seems that the cascade causes that redundant left outer join.

any help?

Answer (score 2):

i finally decided to rip out cascades and take care of relationships by myself. Cascades added complexity in SQL (joins) and overhead in performance.

I think that issue with cascades need some more discussion here.

Think about a back bone entity like a USER which has some basic fields (fname, lname, etc..) and many relationships with other entities like (FRIENDSHIPS, PRIVATE_MESSAGES, etc)

If i use cascade (CascadeType.ALL) anytime i want to merge a USER hibernate fetch the entity from database but also adds a performance improvement fetching also the state of some relationships (e.g. FRIENDSHIPS) which in most of cases is redundant.

I am also attaching another post describing the same issue:

[Using cascades optionally in Hibernate/JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392538/using-cascades-optionally-in-hibernate-jpa)

Maybe anyone with more experience would gine any advice here?

I personally chose to rip out cascades and do all the relationships stuff manually.

Answer (score 0):

the left outer join is a performance improvement to fetch the user and the loaded association in one go which is needed for the merge to know the database state. if you set it to lazy it is not loaded when merging and therefor it does not have to load it to merge the changes.

Comment: Hi Firo thanks for your immediate answer.

The point is that i have more than one relationships like the one above and the hibernate is always makes this outer join with the first alphabetically. Why is not including all relationships but only one?

Can i disable that outer join but keep also the cascade ALL?

Comment: maybe this one has changed somehow or is not lazy loaded for some reason?